# MPAndroid chart combined chart not displaying data

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I am trying to use MPAndroid chart to display 2 sets of data. There is no syntax error or crash but no data is being displayed. Here's my code.

```
ublic class WorkoutSummary extends Activity {
private CombinedChart mChart;
List<Float> hr_list = new ArrayList<Float>();
List<Float> calorie_list = new ArrayList<>();
List<Float> steps = new ArrayList<Float>();
List<String> time_check_hr = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> time_check_steps = new ArrayList<>();

TextView calorie;

float total_calories = 0;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.workoutsummary);


    mChart = (CombinedChart) findViewById(R.id.chart_workout);

    CombinedData data = new CombinedData();
    data.setData(lineData());
    data.setData(barData());
    mChart.setData(data);
    mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    mChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mChart.setDrawBorders(false);


    mChart.getXAxis().setEnabled(false);

}

// this method is used to create data for line graph
public LineData lineData(){
    ArrayList<Entry> line = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Float x: hr_list){
     line.add(new Entry(x,hr_list.indexOf(x)));
        Log.d("Line is", String.valueOf(line));
        Log.d("time hr", String.valueOf(time_check_hr));

    }

    LineDataSet lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(line, "Heart Rate");
    lineDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

    mChart.invalidate();
    LineData lineData = new LineData(time_check_hr,lineDataSet);

    return lineData;

}

// this method is used to create data for Bar graph
public BarData barData(){

    ArrayList<BarEntry> group1 = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Float x: steps){
        group1.add(new BarEntry(x,steps.indexOf(x)));

}
    BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(group1, "Steps");
    barDataSet.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 155, 0));
    barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
    Log.d("group1 is", String.valueOf(group1.size()));
    Log.d("time steps", String.valueOf(time_check_steps.size()));

    BarData barData = new BarData(time_check_steps,barDataSet);

    return barData;

}
```

The page crashes every time I run. The log says, "One or more of the DataSet Entry arrays are longer than the x-values array of this ChartData object." I logged my x-axis values and checked, the size of both the arrays are same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to initialize the constructor properly. You have to pass X-axis string array or arraylist in the constructor. In your case it would be time_check whatever, either hr or steps.

Comment: oh damn, haha. fixed. =)

Comment: Wass what to the constructor of what? How?